# How can I merge a pr again on Github?

Tags: git, github

In am working with a team on a project on Github, one contributor made a PR, I reviewed it and decided to `git merge` it into the project.

Because the version number in the code wasn’t up to date, I `git push` a new commit with `-f` with the updated version number.

I immediately found out I made a mistake because my local code wasn’t *up to date*, so I have override the code in GitHub with my local project version, and now the PR they made is lost from the main branch because I had an older version.

How do I go back to the version of the project when I merged the PR? So the override I did is “removed”?

Comment: Hard reset? It's a bit unclear what the state of affairs is.

Comment: @matt my interpretation is OP committed locally to an out of date version of `main`, and then force pushed that, blowing away the recently completed PR on `main`.

Comment: @TTT Yeah, this is why I suggest hard reset along with a question mark. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the commit ID of the completed PR. Looking at the history of the PR should provide it, typically near the bottom of a completed PR you'll see something like:

> Username merged commit a1b2c3d into main 3 hours ago

Once you know the commit ID:

```
git fetch
# create a copy of the current origin/main so you can look at it afterwards
git branch copy-of-origin-main origin/main --no-track
git switch main
git reset --hard <commit-id-of-completed-pr>
git push --force-with-lease
# At this point main is back to how it was before you forced push before

# now make your change properly
git log copy-of-origin-main # copy the commit ID of your version number fix
git cherry-pick <commit-ID-of-version-number-fix>
git push

# now you can delete your temp branch
git branch -D copy-of-origin-main
```

**Tips:**

1. The fact that you had to force push `main` should have been a red flag. You almost never want to force push shared branches such as `main` unless it's an emergency fix up. Even in an emergency `revert` should be considered (which would be a regular push) over `reset` which requires a force push.
2. When force pushing (hopefully not a shared branch), best practice would be to use `git push --force-with-lease` instead of `git push --force` (same as `-f` like you did). Adding the "-with-lease" suffix will stop the force push if there are new commits on the remote branch that you haven't fetched yet. Maybe that would have stopped you, depending on the last time you fetched. (If you got an error at that point you may have realized you needed to pull to update main.)
3. I personally try to avoid having local copies of shared branches whenever possible, in part because they go out of date quickly and you might accidentally use an out of date version of it (like you did). When I do need to check out a shared branch for some reason, I delete it as soon as I'm done with it. I also use `origin/main` when creating new branches or updating my local branches with a merge/rebase.
4. Consider locking your `main` branch so that everyone needs to use a PR. There's nothing wrong with using a PR for your quick version update fix just like a regular change.